# pick an element from a Set based on its property

Tags: java, set

```
Set<Employee> employeeSet =
```

How can I pick the oldest Employee from the Set (it has a property 'int age')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best solution for performance, but you could iterate through each element using an enhanced for loop:

```
Employee oldest = employeeSet.get(0); // Initialize with the first index
for (Employee emp : employeeSet) {
    if (emp.age > oldest.age) {
        oldest = emp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Stream API

```
Optional<Employee> employee = employeeSet.stream()
                                         .max(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.age));
```

`employee.get()` will return the Employee unless the set was empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think Stream interface in Java 8 can help

```
final Comparator<Employee> comp = Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getAge);
Employee oldest = employeeList.stream()
            .max(comp)
            .get();
```

See detail on this https://stevewall123.wordpress.com/2014/08/31/java-8-streams-max-and-streams-min-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the collection.

```
int maxAge = 0; //  
for(Employee emp: employeeSet){
    if(emp.getAge() > maxAge)
      maxAge = employee.getAge()
}
```

maxAge variable will have the highest age after the forEach loop ends

Answer (score 0):

You can define first Age for find oldest employee 
`int baseAge = 50;` 
Now you need to compare all employee age to this Age

```
  Public Set findOldest()
    {
        int baseAge =50;
        Set < Employee > oldest = new HashSet< Employee >();
        Set<Employee> employee = // your set of employees
        for ( Employee emp : employee )
        {
            If(emp.empAge > baseAge)
                    oldest.add(emp);
        }
        return oldest;
    }
```